# AWS RDS PostgreSQL :all databases grow by the same age

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, amazon-aurora

I'm very new to Postgres.
I know the issue transaction ID wraparound which I should avoid.
In the documentation i also found the hint to look in the database with .
Why I got same age for my all databases while using below script ?

```sql
SELECT datname
     , age(datfrozenxid)
  FROM pg_database
     ;
```

I did the command several times in a few seconds, and this number is growing very quickly.

[image: same age]

Comment: Well, the age is bound to increase if you run the query multiple times with time in between :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under normal settings, the system doesn't even start trying to freeze anything until at least an age of 150,000,000 is reached.  So they will increase in lockstep until then.

Comment: so it means the transaction id will keep growth until it hit the freeze value even thought there are no DML / DDL  ?  I use select txid_current() to check current transaction id .

Comment: txid_current() itself will advance the xid when called outside a transaction block.